# Can I withdraw CHF on a Mastercard pre loaded with euros?

Tags: europe, payment-cards, switzerland

I have a pre-loaded "travel wallet" Mastercard issued by a bank in South Africa. When I loaded it I specified an amount in euro and they issued me a different card for GBP. Can I use the euro card to withdraw Swiss francs in Switzerland, even if that attracts a higher fee? Assume that I cannot use my normal credit card (I did not expect a Switzerland stop so I did not tell the bank that I would be using the other cards there).

**OUTCOME:** At the main train station in Geneva I was able to draw Francs at an ATM which even had the option to debit my card in Euros.

Comment: Most likely yes, but expect to pay premiums upwards of 5% on exchange rate and fees.  The only sure way to know will be to contact the issuer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can. Maestro Cards work with every [ATM](http://www.maestrocard.com/gateway/where/where_atm.html) in Switzerland. The currency of the card doesn't matter. The fees depends on the issuing institute (bank). ATMs of the Swiss Post (the yellow ones) charge an extra fee.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

You'd be better off finding a bureau de change though.

Bureaux de change will usually be able to do the card transaction in euros and as a general rule have better exchange rates than ATMs.

Comment: Source on that? I'd expect accepting the rate that the ATM offers to be poor, but if you opt to be charged in CHF, my experience is that *most* card issuers beat Bureaux, although there are some rip-off exceptions (and fixed fees can be a killer for small withdrawrals)